# Probability of winning in a 3 slots game with 9 types per slot

Tags: probability, gambling

The game is as follows: you have three slots: `[1][2][3]` with the same 9 fair types for each slot.
When all the slots are the same its a win, doesn't matter the type.
`[5][5][5]` = win.

What is the probability of winning in such a game?

What i calculated:
there are 9 winning variations because any 3 of the same 9 types is win
and there are 729 variations (9×9×9)
so 9/729 = 1.234%

What ChatGPT said:
1/729 = 0.13%

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: You are right and chatGPT is wrong.

Comment: ChatGPT does not think, it just strings words and phrases together in a clever way without caring about meaning.  Here it ignored your "When all the slots are the same it's a win" guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p(win\mid x_1 = j) = p(x_1 =\cdots = x_r = j\mid x_1=j) = [idp]= \frac{1}{n^{r-1}}$.

$p(win) = \sum_{j=1}^r p(win\mid x_1 = j)p(x_1=j) = \frac{1}{n^{r-1}}\underbrace{\sum p(x_1=j)}_{1} =\frac{1}{n^{r-1}}$.

In this case, $n,r=9,3$ so $p(win) = \frac{1}{81}$.

Combinatorial, perhaps easier, approach:
$p(win) = \frac{\# \text{winning}}{\#\text{total possible}} = \frac{n}{n^r} = \frac{1}{n^{r-1}}$.